# Issue displaying button with if statement Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a rails app With Rails 4 Ruby 2

> **Background:**

In my show view i have a nested element displaying, in this element I have a custom button to update a record. (displayed below), i have created and if/else statement to either show the button, or if the button has been clicked, show the time it was clicked at.

> **Problem:**

The problem I have encountered is that this works fine when only one line item is present. When I add several line items, and hit the button on the top line it removes all the buttons and shows the 00:00:00 time on the remaining lines.

I would like it so that when I push the button on Line item one, the button then disappears only for that line item, leaving the rest to be clicked.

> **My View Page:**

```
 <table class="table" id="resp-tbl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td><center>UNIT</center></td>
        <td><center>STATUS</center></td>
        <td><center>DISPATCHED </center></td>
        <td><center>RESPONDING </center></td>
        <td><center>ON SCENE </center></td>
        <td><center>CLEAR AT</center></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @respondings.each do |responding| %>
        <tr>
          <td><center><%= responding.user.employee_ident %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= responding.status %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= responding.created_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %></center></td>
          <td><center>
          <% if @respondings_true.present? %>
            <%= responding.responding_tme.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to "Responding", unit_responding_update_call_responding_path(call_id: @call.id, id: responding.id), method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-nav btn-primary', :id => 'respond-btn' %>
          <% end %> 
          <td><center><%= responding.on_scene_tme.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= responding.clear_tme.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %></center></td>
          <td><center><%= link_to "Remove Unit", [@call, responding], class: 'btn btn-danger btn-sm', method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure you want to remove this unit?" %></center></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

> **My Custom Controller Action:**

```
#Custom Controller Calls
  def unit_responding_update
    @call = Call.find(params[:call_id])
    @responding = Responding.find(params[:id])
    @responding.responding_tme = DateTime.now
    @responding.responding = "true"
    @responding.on_scene = "false"
    @responding.clear = "false"
    @responding.status = "RESPONDING"
    @responding.save!
      respond_to do |format|
      if @responding.save
        format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: "Responding time successfully updated." }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

The filter should be reading the update action to status here and only removing the button and replacing it with the time if the `responding.status = RESPONDING`

I added this to my show method in my calls controller.

```
@respondings_true = @call.respondings.select{ |x| x.status == 'RESPONDING'}
```

Like I said above, The action should originally display the button because until the update button is pushed, the status is blank.

Thanks in advance for your assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @respondings_true.present? %>

@respondings_true = @call.respondings.select{ |x| x.status == 'RESPONDING'}
```

Well, the issue is that once you update one line item, @respondings_true would always be true.

the if statement should base on the line item, you can change the if statement to something like

```
<% if responding.status == 'RESPONDING' %>
```